# c: my function does not count any words

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, words

I have been trying to make this function take an array of strings and count the number of words but I keep getting 0 as my answer i.e. it hasn't counted anything. I was wondering if anyone could help me out? I believe the logic is right( i could be wrong) but I am mostly really unsure about the way I would be iterating

thank you!!

Here is my code:

```
int fWords (char **array, int index) {

    int number = 0;
    int i  = 0;
    int in = 0;
    int j  = 0;
    int length = 0;

    while (i < index) {
       length = strlen (array[i]);
       for (j = 0; array[i][j] < length; j++) {
          if (isspace(array[i][j]) != 0) {
              in = 0;
          }
          else if (in == 0) {
             in = 1;
             number++;
          }
       }

       i++;
    }

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset in after every run of the inner loop. Something like this

```
while (i < index) {
   length = strlen (array[i]);
   in = 0;
   //^^^^^^^
   for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      if (isspace(array[i][j]) != 0) {
          in = 0;
      }
      else if (in == 0) {
         in = 1;
         number++;
      }
   }

   i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! that actually fixed all my problems

Comment: @kirkosaur: don't forget to accept an answer if it answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

This condition is incorrect:

```
for (j = 0; array[i][j] < length ; j++)
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

it should be simply

```
for (j = 0; j < length ; j++)
//          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will fix the problem with zero.

Comment: Thank you so much!! that solved my problem well it is actually counting thank god haha but for some reason it is off by quite a bite, I'm assuming it's that i am not passing all the strings correctly or something